# PrimeFaces Theme (Omega) is giving maven plugin error Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, primefaces

Error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: Read the error correctly. Totally not omega them or even PrimeFaces related (nor netbeans)

Comment: What's the question?